# Does Sveltekit have a preview mode?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, headless-cms

Does Sveltekit have a preview mode just like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode) or [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/live-preview/)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing built in as such.
But the approach would be exactly the same as in those frameworks: instead of going to `/posts/my-new-article` you make it such that `/posts/my-new-article?preview` will also get posts that are in `preview` only.

To get the query parameters you can use

```js
export async function get({ query }) {
  const preview = query.get('preview')
}
```

Comment: Does this work with pre-rendering? (auto switch to ssr if preview enabled)